# How to create a quadrant-circle shape-matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Currently I have a problem with creating a matrix with a quadrant-shape. The problem is as follow:

I would like to have a 138 x 140 matrix with values of 2 and 3. Inside and on the quadrant circle, the values should be 2. Everything outside the circle, I need to have a value of 3. The radius of the circle is 138 (=R138). Hopefully the image below will support my explanation.

[image: 138x140 matrix with quadrant circle.]

I was thinking of using 'triu' (and then flip) in matlab: then I will not get a circle, but a triangle instead (have not tried it yet). And that is not what I want.

What is the simplest way to create this matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
a = ones(138, 140)*3;
[gx, gy] = meshgrid(139:-1:0, 137:-1:0);
a(gx.*gx + gy.*gy <= 138*138) = 2;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I get the error "Attempt to grow array along ambiguous dimension.".

Comment: Thanks for your update, it works now. To check graphically: ```imagesc( a ); axis tight; axis equal;``` :]

Comment: Thanks, it is a very nice solution! I checked it graphically as well, but the resolution seems to be very coarse. Is there a way to smooth it either A) in matrix or B) graphically (preferably the first one)?